# Rename file and remove 2,3,4 and last lines in file data and move the file to another folder

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have few files in a Unix folder

```
Ex: Myfile_20211121_073749
    Myfile_20211120_063448
    Myfile_20211119_053345
```

I want to sort files based on timestamp asc and pick the first file, rename the file to remove last underscore

```
Myfile_20211119053345
```

Then move file to another folder removing line 2,3,4 and last line in data of the file

```
file data:  line1
            line2
            line3
            line4
            restofthelines
            lastline

 tobe:      line1
            restofthelines
```

Comment: Which part in particular do you need help with?

Comment: removing lines in file and storing into another path

Comment: Look at piping `find` into `sort | head -n 1` to get the file name. Remove the underscore with `a=Myfile_20211121_073749; b=${a%_*}; echo $b${a##*_}`. You can delete the lines with `sed '2,4d; $d'`.